# Identity Server Single Log Out Functionality is Not Working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an identity server4 app and two client apps. One client app is mvc core app which is using code flow and other is asp.net web forms app which is using implicit flow. I am trying to achieve single log out functionality by implementing front channel logout URL. Front channel logout URL method does get hit in both client app if user logout from any of the client. The problem is that when i logs out from mvc client then it also logs me out from web forms app but when i logs out from web forms app it does not logs me out from mvc app.

Comment: did you set a cookie on your MVC web application?

Comment: i am not setting any explicit coockies in mvc app

Comment: services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";

            })